# Angular JS custom filter not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm new, meaning this is my first hour with AngularJS. I'm trying to get a hang of writing custom filters, and here is my first one:

http://jsfiddle.net/rutwick/UJTdb/

```
angular.module('myfilters', []).
filter('addon', function(){
        alert('here');
        return function(ip){
            return ip+'-suffix';
        }
    });
angular.module('myapp', ['myfilters']);
```

If I try using it like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />
<h1>{{ sometext | addon }}</h1>
```

I get a whole lotta errors. So I use it like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sometext" />
<h1>{{ sometext | filter:addon }}</h1>
```

No errors, but it doesn't work. The alert doesn't pop. Am I missing something here?

**Errors:**

```
Error: Unknown provider: addonFilterProvider <- addonFilter
at Error (<anonymous>)...blah blah file path
```

Comment: what are the errors ? Is there a plunker somewhere?

Comment: Check now, I've added the error.

Comment: You need to register your filter with your app. Is "angular" your application name?

Comment: Works like it should for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/0PkNAMXdPBp6jVnpns5U?p=preview

Comment: Here's my entire code: http://jsfiddle.net/rutwick/UJTdb/

Comment: Does it have something to do with the version? I'm using v1.1.5

Comment: Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UJTdb/3/

Comment: Just included Angular 1.1.1 and selected "no wrap in body"

Comment: I'm using a recent version, 1.1.5. And how do I use nowrap in my local code?

Comment: Also you have to write <body ng-app="myapp">

Comment: @RutwickGangurde It's not version related...

Comment: Ohh yes. `ng-app="myapp"` works well! Please add this as an answer and I'll accept it! Thanks mate, you stopped me from running away from AngularJS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
```

does the trick! :D

Answer (score 2):

See updated variant here http://jsfiddle.net/UJTdb/6/

Basic idea was to set `<body ng-app="myapp">`

Also I changed a filter function:

```
filter('addon', function(){
        alert('here');
        return function(ip){
            return ip || '' +'-suffix';
        }
    });
```